# Managing GameCenter Contacts

Tags: ipad, game-center

Is there a way to manage GameCenter contacts without having to be on the iPad?

I often come across people who I want to add to my GameCenter contacts while browsing various forums. I do this browsing from my Windows PC. Is there any way I can manage who is a GameCenter Friend while not having physical access to the iPad at the time? Is there maybe a section on the Apple website that allows this, or within iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Mac Game Center app that was added in Mountain Lion, but besides that there is currently no way to access Game Center outside of the iOS app.

A place to keep an eye on would be iCloud.com. If Apple added a web interface to Game Center it would most likely be added there (/speculation)